# php and ssl on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: openssl, paypal-sandbox, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

When running `$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);` I get a 500 internal server error and it fails completely.

When running `$fp = fsockopen ('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);` I get an exception:

> Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable
>   it when you configured PHP?

When I run `php -i | grep -i openssl` I get

```
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

As if ssl is enabled and configured correctly.
in php.ini the extension=...ssl is commented out with `;` so I'm confused. How can I proceed from here to make it work?

Thanks

Added phpinfo output of SSL
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ssl:// is correct for fsockopen, not https://

Try ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com, and try with curl

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php

Comment: I'm using pdt and not ipn so I took the pdt code and put some echo as debug. Looks like $ch = curl_init(); is stuck, even a try/catch is not triggering

Comment: running curl -I https://www.google.com from ssh shows results, meaning curl is there and working